# What is the correlation between self and other ratings of goal orientation?

Tags: learning, educational-psychology, goals

In educational psychology [goal orientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goal-oriented) is a popular construct. In particular popular dimensions of goal orientation include performance-approach, performance-avoidance, and mastery. The studies that I have read (e.g., Elliot et al, 1999) have used self-report measures of goal orientation. I.e., students have been asked to rate themselves.

In general, I am sceptical of people's self-ratings of their performance or strategy. Thus, I was wondering how well self-ratings correlated with other ratings (e.g., by knowledgeable teachers or other careful observers).

#### Questions

- **What is the correlation between self and other ratings for goal orientation?**
- **How do correlations between goal orientation and performance vary based on whether the goal orientations ratings are by the self or an other?**

#### References

- Elliot, A.J., McGregor, H.A. & Gable, S. (1999). Achievement goals, study strategies, and exam performance: A mediational analysis.. Journal of educational psychology, 91, 549. [PDF](http://www.psych.rochester.edu/research/apav/publications/documents/1999_ElliotMcGregorGable_AchievementgoalsStudyStrategiesandExamPerformance.pdf)

Comment: Do you have your existing data? Would you like to differentiate the two (self-rating vs other rating)?